# How do I implement single click editing on cell in a table in wxPython?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I have a table where I originally had the issue of needing to click 3 times on a cell in order for it to show the dropdown / combobox list of devices I need it to display.

After some chatgpt, I managed to get it to work with double click as seen here:

```
def on_single_click_edit(self, event):
    row = event.GetRow()
    col = event.GetCol()

    # Move the grid cursor to the clicked cell
    self.rear_device_grid.SetGridCursor(row, col)
    self.front_device_grid.SetGridCursor(row, col)

    # Enable the editor for the current cell
    self.rear_device_grid.EnableCellEditControl()
    self.front_device_grid.EnableCellEditControl()

    # Force the grid to start the editor
    self.rear_device_grid.ShowCellEditControl()
    self.front_device_grid.ShowCellEditControl()

    # Skip the event to allow default processing
    event.Skip()
```

Here is the code of me creating the table(s):

```
 # Creating rear device table
    self.rear_device_grid = wx.grid.Grid(self)
    self.rear_device_grid.CreateGrid(8, 1)
    self.rear_device_grid.SetDefaultColSize(130, resizeExistingCols=False)
    self.rear_device_grid.SetColLabelValue(0, "Rear Device Slots")

    # Set the editor for "Device" column to be a choice editor with module list
    module_choice_editor = wx.grid.GridCellChoiceEditor(self.module_list, allowOthers=False)
    for row in range(self.rear_device_grid.GetNumberRows()):
        self.rear_device_grid.SetCellEditor(row, 0, module_choice_editor)

    grid.Add(self.rear_device_grid, pos=(7,0), span=(3,3))

    self.front_device_grid = wx.grid.Grid(self)
    self.front_device_grid.CreateGrid(5, 1)
    self.front_device_grid.SetDefaultColSize(130, resizeExistingCols=False)
    self.front_device_grid.SetColLabelValue(0, "Front Device Slots")
    self.front_device_grid.SetRowLabelValue(4, "Crosspoint:")

    # Change row labels of front device from 1-4 to 9-12
    start_label = 9
    for i in range(4): # Loop through first 4 rows
        self.front_device_grid.SetRowLabelValue(i, str(start_label + i))

    # Set the editor for "Device" column to be a choice editor with module list
    for row in range(self.front_device_grid.GetNumberRows() - 1):  # Exclude the last row
        self.front_device_grid.SetCellEditor(row, 0, module_choice_editor)

    # Set the editor for the last row "Crosspoint:" to be a choice editor with crosspoint list
    crosspoint_choice_editor = wx.grid.GridCellChoiceEditor(self.crosspoint_list, allowOthers=False)
    self.front_device_grid.SetCellEditor(4, 0, crosspoint_choice_editor)  # Last row for crosspoint

    grid.Add(self.front_device_grid, pos=(10,0), span=(3,3))
```

Comment: When asking a question on SO, it's best if you make the question as clear as possible. Think of us, as idiot savants. The best questions, illustrate the problem with runnable code, not disembodied fragments. This is because whilst it's obvious to you, we have literally no idea, what we are looking at half of the time. Best of luck.